# jenkins maven PluginResolutionException

Tags: java, maven, jenkins, build, nexus

I'm trying to build with jenkins, eclipse, nexus, svn.

After uploaded maven-archiver 2.5 to nexus, this error evoke.

[image]

> [ERROR] Plugin org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-resources-plugin:2.6 or
>   one of its dependencies could not be resolved: Failure to find
>   org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-resources-plugin:jar:2.6 in
>   http://192.168.56.1:8081/nexus/content/repositories/KCC_Central/ was
>   cached in the local repository, resolution will not be reattempted
>   until the update interval of KCC_Central has elapsed or updates are
>   forced -> [Help 1] [ERROR]  [ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the
>   errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch. [ERROR] Re-run Maven using
>   the -X switch to enable full debug logging. [ERROR]  [ERROR] For more
>   information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the
>   following articles: [ERROR] [Help 1]
>   http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/PluginResolutionException

So as you can see in next picuture, I uploaded this pom and jar.

[image]

[image]

But still jenkins say maven-resources-plugin 2.6 is not in my repository.

So how can I avoid this error?

plus : added two jar files, still error evoke.

[image]

[image]

Comment: But the nexus screenshots do not show the JAR, just the POM

Comment: Oh.. Sorry I forget to click "add artifact"

Comment: But after add jar file, error still evoke. sad.

Comment: Try add the -U flag to force updates: mvn install -U. Alternatively delete the maven-resource-plugin folder that was cached in the local repo Jenkins uses

Comment: thanks, I solved it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This error means I did not have other plugins that maven-resources-plugin has dependency.

So I download these plugin.